# How do I grep output from git?

Tags: bash, grep, git

I'm trying to extract the name of the folder created by git. The output says:

```
...
Cloning into 'repository-name'...
...
```

I want to pipe this output into grep to extract the one line that says `Cloning into 'repository-name'`. However, when I run `git clone https://github.com/username/repository-name.git | grep "Cloning into"`, git appears to bypass grep and print output directly to the screen, since I get the full git output message with no grep highlighting. Sending the --no-pager flag to git doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `git-clone` man page:

> --progress
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default when it is attached to a terminal, unless --quiet is specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

So we have to do [Redirecting of Standard Descriptors](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-redirect-stderr-stdout/) as git-clone outputs on the standard error stream.

This will probably do

`git clone https://github.com/username/repository-name.git --progress 2>&1 | grep "Cloning into"`

Comment: That's a bit weird that they would print to stderr even when there are no errors... But thanks @Aaryan for the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised too, but probably they had a reason for this, maybe some extensive search on the net will give us some discussion forum ( just guessing ).

Comment: [This mailing list thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-push-output-goes-into-stderr-td6758028.html) has a take on the issue.